# Python selenium code scrolls down successfully but id can`t print content of tweet

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\SeleniumDrivers\chromedriver')
def find_hashtags(hashtag):
    driver.get('https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + hashtag + '?src=hash')
    body=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,0.5)
    while True:
            try:
                    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(@class, 'Icon Icon--large Icon--logo')]")))
                    print("error")
                    break
            except:
                    body.send_keys(Keys.END)

    tweets=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tweet-text')
    for tweet in tweets:
            print (tweet.text)
find_hashtags("any hashtag")
```

When i run it on chrome it scrolls sccessfully but it cant print tweets content so there arent any problems in webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you locators are incorrect. Use CSS selectors.

Second, if you want text to be printed in a loop, put it there.
And last: you need to wait for your elements to become visible.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re
import os

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')


def find_hashtags(hashtag):
    driver.get('https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + hashtag + '?src=hash')
    body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    while True:
        try:
            wait.until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'Icon Icon--large Icon--logo')]")))
            print("error")
            break
        except:
            body.send_keys(Keys.END)
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-901oao.r-18jsvk2.r-1qd0xha.r-a023e6.r-16dba41.r-rjixqe.r-bcqeeo.r-bnwqim.r-qvutc0>span:nth-of-type(1)")))
            tweets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.css-901oao.r-18jsvk2.r-1qd0xha.r-a023e6.r-16dba41.r-rjixqe.r-bcqeeo.r-bnwqim.r-qvutc0>span:nth-of-type(1)')
            for tweet in tweets:
                print(tweet.text)


find_hashtags("any hashtag")
```

Also, note that `0.5` seconds wait is too small.

Comment: When i tried a while later it stop loading as i wanted but it prints last tweet and code doesnt stops printing it

Comment: Put break and condition when you want it to stop loading. I think the your main question is answered

Comment: I cant upvote i can only accept it and i accepted it